# msg.val payable compiler implimentation optcode

Tags: evm

How does the ethereum evm handle msg.val transfers?   There is no opt code I can see which changes the balance of an account.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the ethereum evm handle msg.val transfers? There is no opt
> code I can see which changes the balance of an account.

You are right, this is not an opcode at all. It's a property of a message call (*i.e.,* msg.value). This is handled even before the actual code execution as you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go#L168) in go-ethereum with :

```
evm.Context.Transfer(evm.StateDB, caller.Address(), addr, value)
```

And only then, the actual [code execution](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go#L228) takes place.

Comment: Just for completeness, the opcode to transfer ether would be CALL, and the opcode to read the received amount would be CALLVALUE.